# How should the iOS 15.0.1 Safari collapsed/minimized address/URL/domain bar be handled?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, safari, ios15

It seems that `window.innerHeight` does not factor it in.  This results in it overlaying content undesirably.  See the screenshot below.

[1st Gen iPhone SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuR2K.png)

I have tried using `env(safe-area-inset-bottom)` after adding `viewport-fit=cover` to the `meta[name="viewport"]` element in hopes that it would evaluate to being the height of the collapsed domain bar but it seems to be evaluating to 0.

I measured its height on a 1st gen iPhone SE as being `22px`.  It seems that it is significantly taller than that on an iPhone 11.

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: iOS 15.1 Safari handles the collapsed address bar a lot better; at least in our case.  We decided to only support iOS Safari 15.1 so this issue is no longer a concern for me.